# Manage nested queries for mysql in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, nested

I'm trying to create a function for writing to a MySql database instance through a Node.js application using the `mysql` npm package.
I created something that works but I'm not satisfied because this code seems too much complicated with 4 nested `if`s.
I retrieve a connection from the connection pool and I can have an error. Then, only if I don't have an error, I can try to start a transaction, and potentially another error can be generated. At this point, only if the transaction starts correctly I can run a query but also here another error can potentially occur. Finally, the transaction is ready to be committed but also here another error can be generated.

I'm used to Java `try / catch / finally` and not an expert of JavaScript but I really like this language and would like to understand better how to manage functions, callbacks and promises.
I don't understand if it's the library that doesn't allow to make cleaner code or what.

Can someone help me in improving the readability and maintainability of this code?

```js
import mysql from "mysql";

// Creating the connection pool 
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: "SOME_HOST",
    user: "SOME_USER",
    port: "SOME_PORT",
    password: "SOME_PASSWORD",
    database: "SOME_DB_NAME"
});


function runQueries() {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err; // not connected!
        connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            connection.query("some query", function (error, results) {
                if (error) {
                    return connection.rollback(function () {
                        throw error;
                    });
                }
                connection.commit(function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                        return connection.rollback(function () {
                            throw error;
                        });
                    }
                });
                console.log(results);
            });
        });
        if (connection) connection.release();
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used [Node MySQL 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) with a ["promise pool"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper): is much more readable, linear, and allows to use `try/catch/finally` blocks consistently.

```
import mysql from "mysql2";

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: "SOME_HOST",
    user: "SOME_USER",
    port: "SOME_PORT",
    password: "SOME_PASSWORD",
    database: "SOME_DB_NAME"
});
const promisePool = pool.promise();

async function runQueries() {
    let connection;
    try {
        connection = await promisePool.getConnection();
        await connection.beginTransaction();
        const results = await connection.query("some query");
        await connection.commit();
        console.log(results); // or console.table(results);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    finally {
        if (connection) connection.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using async/await https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
const runQueries = async () => {
    const connection = await pool.getConnection()
    await connection.beginTransaction()
    const { error, results } = await connection.query("some query")
    if (error) return connection.rollback( 
    console.log(results)
    if (connection) await connection.release();          
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think that is correct.
Firstly, the IntelliSense tells me that the ```await``` before ```pool.getConnection()``` is useless.
Then, I have an error "Cannot read property 'beginTransaction' of undefined\n..." I think because the connection is not retrieved properly in this way.

Comment: I just rewritten the code in async await style improving the readability and maintainability as you asked) You didn't ask to configure msql connection pool)